# I want the full file path of the image file which is represented in the file tag into my servlet

Tags: java, file, input

/*This is my html page*/

```
<form method="post"  action="/college/reg" >
<input type="file" name="image" ></input>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" ></input>

</form>
```

This is my question. 
Here i am uploading the image file. The Path I gave is an image file i.e.,
F:\photos\flower.jpg but i am not getting this path in the servlet. I am getting like this as below:

```
String s1=request.getParameter("image");
System.out.println("s1");
```

I am getting the output like this "flower.jpg"
but  i want the total file path i.e.,F:\photos\flower.jpg

Then i can save it in my oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

The path "F:\photos\flower.jpg" is given on the client side,
so why does it important to the server side?

If it's so important, you can send (as a hidden input field) also the value of `<input type="file" name="image" >`.  Just set (on submit) the hidden input's value to be equal to the file input value.